# Access symmetric key generated by EVP_Seal/EVP_Open functions?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to set up a bidirectional encryption scheme between a client and server using the OpenSSL crypto API.

I have generated an RSA public/private key pair for the server. I wanted to use the `EVP_Seal/Open` functions to generate a symmetric key to be used for session encryption. The client uses the public key to encrypt a symmetric key and send it to the server using `EVP_Seal`. The server then uses `EVP_Open` to decrypt messages... but how do I now encrypt messages to send *back* to the client?

I don't actually have access to unencrypted the symmetric key, so I can't make calls to `EVP_EncryptInit` and the like. How do I encrypt information to send back to the client? I was under the impression I was generating a bi-directional symmetric key with these functions, but I can't figure out how to use it.

I considered sending a second symmetric key that I just generate myself (using, say, `RAND_bytes`) as a "message" that the server could then decrypt, but it seems like I should be able to use the symmetric key that was already generated instead of making a new one.

I also considered using the *encrypted* symmetric key output from `EVP_Seal` as my actual symmetric key and passing *that* as the message for the server to use for encryption, but that also seemed really weird and incorrect.

Comment: @zaph I'm using raw TCP sockets, so HTTP/S isn't an option.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? I can't seem to parse it.

Comment: @jww How do I get the symmetric key generated by the EVP_Open/EVP_Seal combination of functions?